# Dynamic update of a label withMathJax in Shiny UI

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using `shiny::updateSliderInput` to update the label of a slider.  I would like the label for the slider to render with the Greek character xi (ξ) and a subscript. The subscript is target of the `updateSliderInput` call.

I've been successful generating the label without the `updateSliderInput` call, but correctly using the `withMathJax()` call for the label update has not worked as well as I would prefer.

A reproducible example of a shiny app for this issue is:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(sliderInput("order", withMathJax("Order, \\(k\\)"), min = 3, max = 7, value = 4, step = 1), 
                                sliderInput("iknots", "iKnots", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5, step = 1),
                                sliderInput("xi1", withMathJax(), min = 0, max = 10, value = 1, step = 0.1))), 
          server = shinyServer(function(input, output, clientData, session) { 
                               observe({
                                 k <- as.integer(input$order)
                                 l <- as.integer(input$iknots) 
                                 updateSliderInput(session, "xi1", label = paste0("\\(\\xi_{", k + l, "}\\)"))
                               }) 
                        }))
```

Upon initial loading of the app in browser we have a the desirable label, the ξ<sub>9</sub> is correct.

[image]

After adjusting either of the first two sliders, the label for the third slider does not render as expected.

[image]

I've tried using `withMathJax` in `label` argument of `updateSliderInput` but have had undesirable labels.  Changing the `updateSliderInput` line in the above to

```
updateSliderInput(session, "xi1", label = withMathJax(paste0("\\(\\xi_{", k + l, "}\\)")))
```

and setting the `sliderInput` to have the either `label = withMathJax()` or `label = ""` results in the initial label of

[image]

and updated label of

[image]

How can the subscript on the ξ be correctly updated in the slider label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use `renderUI` and `uiOutput` to create the last slider otherwise the javascript used to display the MathJax is not called when you update the label.

You could do:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(sliderInput("order", withMathJax("Order, \\(k\\)"), min = 3, max = 7, value = 4, step = 1), 
                                sliderInput("iknots", "iKnots", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5, step = 1),
                                uiOutput("lastSlider"))), 

         server = shinyServer(function(input, output, clientData, session) { 
           output$lastSlider<- renderUI({
             k <- as.integer(input$order)
             l <- as.integer(input$iknots) 
             sliderInput("xi1",label =  withMathJax(paste0("\\(\\xi_{", k + l, "}\\)")), min = 0, max = 10, step = 0.1,value=input$xi1)
           })

         }))
```

Comment: Is there way to make it not "stutter" when dynamically updating the math output? I saw a solution [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1634#issuecomment-252549651) where someone suggests to render the math in a hidden element before swapping it with a visible one, but I didn't really get it to work