# mathjax not working in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, mathjax

I have been trying to add some simple mathjax expression into my shiny app and failed all the way.
I then looked at some online examples and even these would not run on my computer.
For example,  I tried to run the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807003/dynamic-update-of-a-label-withmathjax-in-shiny-ui)  and the mathjax expression did not show.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(sliderInput("order", withMathJax("Order, \\(k\\)"), min = 3, max = 7, value = 4, step = 1), 
                                sliderInput("iknots", "iKnots", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5, step = 1),
                                uiOutput("lastSlider"))), 

         server = shinyServer(function(input, output, clientData, session) { 
           output$lastSlider<- renderUI({
             k <- as.integer(input$order)
             l <- as.integer(input$iknots) 
             sliderInput("xi1",label =  withMathJax(paste0("\\(\\xi_{", k + l, "}\\)")), min = 0, max = 10, step = 0.1,value=input$xi1)
           })

         }))
```

[image]

Do you have any ideas why this could be?
Here is the output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.0.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.4  R6_2.2.2        htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.4     yaml_2.1.16     Rcpp_0.12.16   
 [7] jsonlite_1.5    digest_0.6.13   xtable_1.8-2    httpuv_1.3.5    mime_0.5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work for other users as well (see the question).
Any ideas what could be the problem at my computer?

Comment: Could you include a `sessionInfo()` output?

Comment: I edited the question and included the output. Thank you

Comment: The only more up to date packages i have are `httpuv_1.3.6.2`,  `yaml_2.1.18`,  `digest_0.6.15`. What R-Studio version are you using?

Comment: I am using the newest version of R-Studio: 1.1.442
I tried to update the packages but still it does not work :/

Comment: I am using an older Version (R-Studio 1.0.143 and R 3.4.3), but I hope thats not the reason for that bug..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(

  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      withMathJax(),
      sliderInput("order", "Order, \\(k\\)", min = 3, max = 7, value = 4, step = 1), 
      sliderInput("iknots", "iKnots", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5, step = 1),
      uiOutput("lastSlider")
    )
  ), 

  server = shinyServer(function(input, output, clientData, session) { 
    output$lastSlider<- renderUI({
      k <- as.integer(input$order)
      l <- as.integer(input$iknots) 
      tagList(
        withMathJax(),
        sliderInput("xi1", label = paste0("\\(\\xi_{", k + l, "}\\)"), 
                    min = 0, max = 10, step = 0.1, value=input$xi1)
      )
    })

  }))
```

[image]